# Eigen: Reduction operations very slow with custom scalar type

Tags: eigen

This is an [issue](https://github.com/EmbersArc/Epigraph/issues/7) that came up when profiling my [convex optimization library](https://github.com/EmbersArc/Epigraph/). It uses a non-primitive [custom Scalar type](https://github.com/EmbersArc/Epigraph/blob/master/include/expressions.hpp#L13). We found that reduction operations like `sum()` and `squaredNorm()` are very slow compared to raw loops.

Here's a minimal example to reproduce the issue:

```
#include "epigraph.hpp"

size_t T = 200;

cvx::OptimizationProblem qp;

cvx::MatrixX u = qp.addVariable("u", 1, T);

// this takes very long
cvx::Scalar u_sum = u.sum(); 

// a raw loop is about 5x faster
cvx::Scalar sum = 0.;
for (int i = 0; i < u.size(); i++)
{
    sum += u(i);
}
```

I did some profiling but could not get to the root of the issue since the reduction implementations are somewhat convoluted. I suspect that this has to do with internal optimizations that turn out to be slower in this case lead to a lot of allocations. Is there a way to turn those optimizations off?

[Profiler Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnK79.png)

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations enabled? (And optionally also `-DNDEBUG`). For custom types `u.sum()` should optimize to the same code as a manual loop.

Comment: @chtz I used -O3 to compile. It's the same with the latest GCC and Clang compilers. A raw loop is about 5x faster in the case of `sum()`. I updated the original description.

Comment: It appears that (after inlining) Eigen essentially does `sum = sum + u(i);`, which is of course much slower than `sum += u(i);` if creating/moving objects produces overhead. In theory, you could specialize some internal templates of Eigen, to get the same calls -- patching Eigen is probably more difficult (this would require significant restructuring).

Comment: It looks like you're right. Any idea if we can make it use `operator+=`? What internal templates would have to be specialized? Maybe `scalar_sum_op`?

Comment: You'd need a specialization of `internal::redux_impl`: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/master/Eigen/src/Core/Redux.h If you'd wanted to redesign Eigen to always use `+=` that whole logic (any many dependencies) would need to get redesigned. I should add that specializing internal functions is not safe. The internal API may change at any time.